# URLSessionDownloadDelegate doesn't appear to play well with different threads

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I'm using `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, and specifically this method:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
```

to get completed downloads from my server.

I just completed a set of changes to my app to ensure it's not changing its local data structures concurrently. I'm using a serial queue:

```
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "MyLibrary")
```

to do all the changes to those data structure changes.

Since my URL session delegates access some of those data structures, I went ahead and wrapped *all* of the code in

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
```

in my serial queue.

I then started seeing failures in my app:

```
2021-02-28 19:32:17.105 [Error] [main] [ServerInterface.swift:101] userEvent(_:event:) > Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “SyncServer.A6590254-C807-46CD-B817-9A4D011CBD3A.dat” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Temporary”." UserInfo={NSFileOriginalItemLocationKey=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4B605C28-FB25-4A4B-ACB1-BDCDD9D906AF/Documents/Temporary/SyncServer.A6590254-C807-46CD-B817-9A4D011CBD3A.dat, NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4B605C28-FB25-4A4B-ACB1-BDCDD9D906AF/Documents/Temporary/SyncServer.A6590254-C807-46CD-B817-9A4D011CBD3A.dat, NSFileNewItemLocationKey=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4B605C28-FB25-4A4B-ACB1-BDCDD9D906AF/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/biz.SpasticMuffin.SharedImages/CFNetworkDownload_LcEyLI.tmp, NSUnderlyingError=0x28155efa0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CFNetworkDownload_LcEyLI.tmp” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4B605C28-FB25-4A4B-ACB1-BDCDD9D906AF/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/biz.SpasticMuffin.SharedImages/CFNetworkDownload_LcEyLI.tmp, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4B605C28-FB25-4A4B-ACB1-BDCDD9D906AF/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/biz.SpasticMuffin.SharedImages/CFNetworkDownload_LcEyLI.tmp, NSUnderlyingError=0x28155d980 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}})
```

When I remove this usage of the `serialQueue` above, the problems don't occur.

I'm going to make a change so that the initial downloaded file access (i.e., to move the file to one under my control) occurs prior to the use of the `serialQueue`, but I'd like to know why this is happening. Is the file access from the URL session delegate specific to thread? i.e., in some manner not thread safe?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you dispatch to your serial queue synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: It was asynchronously.

Comment: Changed it to synchronous and now it's working. Makes sense in retrospect. The URL session system is likely just discarding the file earlier than my async thread access was getting to it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate/1411575-urlsession) for this delegate method states that the `location` parameter specifies:

> A file URL for the temporary file. Because the file is temporary, you must either open the file for reading or move it to a permanent location in your app’s sandbox container directory before returning from this delegate method.

Since you are dispatching onto your serial queue asynchronously before doing either of these things, the temporary file is being removed before you can process it.

You could, for example [move the file to a new temporary location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1414750-moveitematurl) before dispatching the asynchronous code.